# Using SFML to draw stuff

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to create a scribble clone for a uni project.

My lines are basically a lot of dots. If I draw too quick, the line breaks and I have single dots.
Also, I can't figure out how to draw lines ONLY when a mouse button is pressed.
I tried to put `mouseMoved` into a while loop until `mouseButton` is released but that didn't seem to work. I ended up in an infinite loop.

Here is my code so far:

```
    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {

            int mouseButtonX = event.mouseButton.x;
            int mouseButtonY = event.mouseButton.y;

            int mouseMoveX = event.mouseMove.x;
            int mouseMoveY = event.mouseMove.y;

            setBrushSize(5);

            brush.setRadius(brushSize);
            brush.setPosition(mouseMoveX - brushSize, mouseMoveY - brushSize);
            brush.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
            brush.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Green);
            brush.setOutlineThickness(2);

            switch (event.type) {
            case (sf::Event::Closed):
                window.close();
                break;

            case (sf::Event::KeyPressed):
                if (event.key.control && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::X) {
                    cout << "closing";

                    window.close();
                }

                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R) {
                    cout << "printed";
                    brushColor = setBrushColor(255, 0, 0);
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::G) {
                    brushColor = setBrushColor(0, 255, 0);
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::B) {
                    brushColor = setBrushColor(0, 0, 255);
                }
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                        points.clear();
                    }
                    it = 0;
                }
                break;

            case(sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed):
                points.push_back(point);
                points[it].setRadius(brushSize);
                points[it].setFillColor(brushColor);
                points[it].setPosition(mouseButtonX - brushSize, mouseButtonY - brushSize);
                it++;
                cout << "drawPoint: Pressed X = " << mouseButtonX << " Y = " << mouseButtonY << endl;

                break;

            case(sf::Event::MouseMoved):
                points.push_back(point);
                points[it].setRadius(brushSize);
                points[it].setFillColor(brushColor);
                points[it].setPosition(mouseMoveX - brushSize, mouseMoveY - brushSize);
                it++;
                cout << "drawPoint: Moved X = " << mouseMoveX << " Y = " << mouseMoveY << endl;
                break;
            }
        }


        window.clear(sf::Color(255, 247, 204));
        window.draw(SkechyT);
        window.draw(close);
        window.draw(brush);
        window.draw(color);
        window.draw(clear);


        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(points[i]);
        }

        //window.draw(point);

        window.display();
    }
}


int getBrushSize() {
    return brushSize;
}

void setBrushSize(int num) {
    brushSize = num;

}

sf::Color setBrushColor(int r, int g, int b) {
    return sf::Color(r, g, b);
}

~Visualizer();
```

};

Comment: ***I ended up in an endless loop.*** That is likely because you did not allow for more events. I don't see the while loop you describe however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can modify a `sf::VertexArray` on the fly (basically building a vector drawing app), you can also use a `sf::RenderTexture` as an actual drawing canvas.

Considering you tried drawing lots of small points, I'd assume you're aiming for the latter. What's important here is the fact that  you don't necessarily have to clear render textures between drawing calls and can therefore preserve whatever has been drawn before.

Combined with the original goal – drawing – this becomes very easy.

All you have to do is draw the changes (e.g. when moving the cursor), finalize the render texture (by calling `display()`), and then presenting it using any drawable (like `sf::Sprite`.

I've quickly scribbled together the following example, which should show the concept rather well (and you won't run into an endless loop other than the actual main loop):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), L"SFML Drawing – C to clear, PageUp/PageDown to pick colors", sf::Style::Default);
    // Set a specific frame rate, since we don't want to
    // worry about vsync or the time between drawing iterations
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);
    window.setFramerateLimit(100);

    // First we'll use a canvas to basically store our image
    sf::RenderTexture canvas;
    canvas.create(800, 600);
    canvas.clear(sf::Color::White);

    // Next we'll need a sprite as a helper to draw our canvas
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(canvas.getTexture(), true);

    // Define some colors to use
    // These are all with very low alpha so we
    // can (over-)draw based on how fast we move the cursor
    const std::vector<sf::Color> colors = {
        sf::Color(255, 0, 0, 8),
        sf::Color(255, 255, 0, 8),
        sf::Color(0, 255, 0, 8),
        sf::Color(0, 255, 255, 8),
        sf::Color(0, 0, 255, 8),
        sf::Color(255, 0, 255, 8)
    };

    // We'll need something to actually draw
    // For simplicity, I'm just drawing a circle shape
    // but you could also draw a line, rectangle, or something more complex
    const float brush_size = 25;
    sf::CircleShape brush(brush_size, 24);
    brush.setOrigin(brush_size, brush_size); // Center on the circle's center

    sf::Vector2f lastPos;
    bool isDrawing = false;
    unsigned int color = 0;

    // Apply some default color
    brush.setFillColor(colors[color]);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                switch (event.key.code) {
                    case sf::Keyboard::C:
                        // Clear our canvas
                        canvas.clear(sf::Color::White);
                        canvas.display();
                        break;
                    case sf::Keyboard::PageUp:
                        // Get next color
                        color = (color + 1) % colors.size();
                        // Apply it
                        brush.setFillColor(colors[color]);
                        break;
                    case sf::Keyboard::PageDown:
                        // Get previous color
                        color = (color - 1) % colors.size();
                        // Apply it
                        brush.setFillColor(colors[color]);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::Resized:
                {
                    // Window got resized, update the view to the new size
                    sf::View view(window.getView());
                    const sf::Vector2f size(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y);
                    view.setSize(size); // Set the size
                    view.setCenter(size / 2.f); // Set the center, moving our drawing to the top left
                    window.setView(view); // Apply the view
                    break;
                }
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                // Only care for the left button
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                    isDrawing = true;
                    // Store the cursor position relative to the canvas
                    lastPos = window.mapPixelToCoords({event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y});

                    // Now let's draw our brush once, so we can
                    // draw dots without actually draging the mouse
                    brush.setPosition(lastPos);

                    // Draw our "brush"
                    canvas.draw(brush);

                    // Finalize the texture
                    canvas.display();
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
                // Only care for the left button
                if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                    isDrawing = false;
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                if (isDrawing)
                {
                    // Calculate the cursor position relative to the canvas
                    const sf::Vector2f newPos(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y)));

                    // I'm only using the new position here
                    // but you could also use `lastPos` to draw a
                    // line or rectangle instead
                    brush.setPosition(newPos);

                    // Draw our "brush"
                    canvas.draw(brush);

                    // Finalize the texture
                    canvas.display();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Clear the window
        window.clear(sf::Color(64, 64, 64));

        // Draw our canvas
        window.draw(sprite);

        // Show the window
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once running, you can start drawing using the left mouse button. <kbd>C</kbd> will clear the canvas and <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> allow you to pick a different color:

[image: Screenshot of the example running]

**Edit:** And just to mention it, in the example above, rather than drawing  a circle, you can just draw a `sf::VertexArray` with `sf::Lines` and two vertices: `lastPos` and `newPos`. This way you'll always draw a continuous line. (But you'd obviously have to save/update `lastPos` with the value of `newPos` once you're done.)